# Put in for it first

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> “Turns out some of those b****** didn’t like us getting Christmas week off. It doesn’t matter that we **put in for it first.** They got denied vacation **after it filled up.** Lisa warned me that it happens every year, and since we’re two of the newer ones, we’re the ones who have to fill in for the b****** who’ve called in sick with the ‘flu’ for a week. Unbelievable.”

I get the meaning of the phrase, that they requested for whole week off, before the other girls did, yet they have to fill in for them, since they called in sick.

Can this phrase be construed any differently?

And what is **after it filled up** referring to?

And in a different context, does this sound natural:

> If you want a week off, then you need to put in for it a week prior.

Does "apply for it" work? (You have to apply for it....) What about "request"? (You have to request for....) Can you think of other similar phrases that might be common in this context? Or is "put in" the most likely choice?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are interpreting it correctly.

"after it filled up" presumably refers to the list of those who would be on vacation. There must be a maximum that can be on vacation at the same time in order to continue business operations.

Your proposed sentence sounds natural.
"Apply for it" works. "Request it" would work, but "request for it" does not.

There may be other phrases, and what is used may depend on the language used at individual companies.

Answer (score 1):

In companies or institutions, you have to tell them when you are going on vacation.

The context assumes a list, with people's names and their vacation dates.

You "put in for it" by signing up in some way.

**As places are limited to some number of people for particular dates**, the **list** will "fill up" after some number of people sign up for it.

No, **the term *apply* does not work here.** You apply for a job, position, scholarship or grant. You don't *apply* for vacation at a place where you are working.

- to put in for vacation [assumes dates are asked for]
- to ask for certain vacation dates

Comment: And does "request" work?

Comment: And does "apply for leave" work for?

Comment: @It's about English No, "request" does not really work. Do you say in **your language,** "I *requested* my vacation"? As for *apply*, I do not want to repeat myself. Leave and vacation have the same semantic thrust here.